Is there a nice topological interpretation of $k$-th Cech cohomology over arbitrary sheaves for $k \geq 2$?
$\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal F} \newcommand{\U}{\mathcal U}$ It is well-known that, given a sheaf $\F$ of abelian groups over a topological space $X$ and a (sufficiently nice) open cover $\U$, the zeroth Cech cohomology $H^0(\U, \F)$ is isomorphic to the group of global sections of $\F$: a $0$-cochain is represented by a local section on each $U \in \U$, and the cocycle condition just corresponds to the assertion that each local section matches on intersections. Another well-known fact is that each element of $H^1(\U, \F)$ corresponds to a fibre bundle over $X$ locally modelled on $\F$: a $1$-cocycle corresponds to a transition function between two open sets, the cocycle condition corresponds to the assertion that the transition functions are compatible, and the $1$-coboundaries correspond to those transition functions which give trivial bundles.
However, I have not been able to find any interpretation of the Cech cohomology classes in $H^k(\U, \F)$ for $k \geq 2$ with a similar topological flavour. Here's what I have found:

One can go the abstract route, and define the sheaf cohomology functor to be the right derived functor to the global section functor. In this sense, the intuition for higher cohomology classes is that they measure the deviation of the global section functor from being exact. However, this feels a bit too abstractly algebraic to give direct significance to each class, and it also makes the appearance of transition functions in $H^1$ look like a coincidence.
Alternatively, I have on numerous occasions seen the vague statement that cohomology measures the obstructions to making local things into global things; this certainly relates more pleasingly to the zeroth and first cases. However, I haven't been able to find a precise description of how this is done in any higher rank (is that the right word?) cases.

So, my question is as follows: is there a precise topological interpretation of higher cohomology classes, which properly generalises these two examples? (I'm open to the more abstract sheaf-cohomological description if it relates to the other examples, but my main motivation here is to understand the Cech cohomology.)

From the nPOV the reason it's difficult to find such interpretations is that $n^{th}$ cohomology is fundamentally tied up with objects that live in $n$-categories, and these are really only familiar objects when $n \le 1$. This is the nPOV on cohomology.
Here's the most concrete example I know of. Let $F = \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ be the sheaf of continuous invertible complex-valued functions. You're probably familiar with the idea that $H^1(X, F)$ is the group of isomorphism classes of complex line bundles under tensor product (maybe under some mild hypotheses, I'm not so familiar with sheaf cohomology). $H^2(X, F)$ can be interpreted as a Brauer group classifying certain bundles of algebras $A_x$ over $X$ up to a suitable equivalence relation; these bundles can be thought of as higher line bundles corresponding to the bundle of categories $\text{Mod}(A_x)$. Some people use the language of gerbes to describe this which I don't understand at all.
More concretely, suppose we have a bundle of matrix algebras $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ over $X$. On the one hand, by the Skolem-Noether theorem, the automorphism group of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is $PGL_n(\mathbb{C})$, so such a bundle is classified by nonabelian cohomology $H^1(X, PGL_n(\mathbb{C}))$. But it turns out that this classification is too fine and not the one we want; we want such bundles "up to Morita equivalence." I am actually not sure exactly how to define Morita equivalence in this context but it should be related to the corresponding bundle of categories $\text{Mod}(M_n(\mathbb{C})) \cong \text{Vect}(\mathbb{C})$ being equivalent; for example, bundles of the form $\text{End}(V)$ where $V$ is an $n$-dimensional complex vector bundle are "trivial." This is related to the stuff I said about $n$-categories; Morita equivalence is equivalence in a $2$-category.
We get the classification we want by considering the short exact sequence $1 \to \mathbb{C}^{\times} \to GL_n(\mathbb{C}) \to PGL_n(\mathbb{C}) \to 1$, which induces a slightly longer exact sequence
$$\dots \to H^1(X, GL_n(\mathbb{C})) \to H^1(X, PGL_n(\mathbb{C})) \to H^2(X, \mathbb{C}^{\times})$$
and the class in $H^2(X, \mathbb{C}^{\times})$ turns out to be what we're really after; at least heuristically the connecting homomorphism to this $H^2$ is given by passing from the bundle of matrix algebras to the corresponding bundle of categories.
In the case that $X$ is compact Hausdorff, we can consider the $C^{\ast}$-algebra of continuous sections of our bundle of matrix algebras, and then the class in $H^2(X, \mathbb{C}^{\times})$ that we're after is an invariant called the Dixmier-Douady invariant of this $C^{\ast}$-algebra. IIRC, using bundles of matrix algebras only produces torsion classes in $H^2$, and to get all classes we need to use bundles with fiber $K$, the $C^{\ast}$-algebra of compact operators on the countable-dimensional Hilbert space.

I think the idea of a gerbe is that it's just essentially a notion of a sheaf of categories, with an identification of the coefficient sheaf of groups with a sheaf of automorphisms of those categories; and 1-categories are still fairly familiar objects.  For example, if $X$ is a scheme over a field $k$, then the class of invertible sheaves is a gerbe with automorphism group $\mathscr{O}_X^$, so it corresponds to a canonical element of $H^2(X, \mathscr{O}_X^)$.  (Then, there's the obvious analogy with $H^1(X, \mathscr{F})$ being identified with isomorphism classes of $\mathscr{F}$-torsors.)

@Daniel: isn't that canonical element just $0$, though? To get nonzero classes one needs "twists" of the category of invertible sheaves, I think.
